# Orchard Core IRepository

Tags: asp.net-core, orchardcms

I'm trying to pre-populate a table by doing this. Was trying to see if I can follow the pluralsight tutorial using the latest core version of orchard.

```
private readonly IRepository<ActorRecord> _actorRepository;

Migrations(IRepository<ActorRecord> actorRepository)
    {
        _actorRepository = actorRepository;
    }

public int UpdateFrom8()
{
    _actorRepository.Create(new ActorRecord { Name = "Mark Hamill" });
    _actorRepository.Create(new ActorRecord { Name = "Harrison Ford" });
    _actorRepository.Create(new ActorRecord { Name = "Carrie Fisher" });
    _actorRepository.Create(new ActorRecord { Name = "Peter Cushing" });
    _actorRepository.Create(new ActorRecord { Name = "Alec Guinness" });
    _actorRepository.Create(new ActorRecord { Name = "James Earl Jones" });
    return 9;
}
```

I couldn't find the equivalent code for repository... Anyone knows?

Comment: This tutorial is for Orchard 1.x. Orchard Core's architecture, especially for data access, is very different, so very little of it will apply. If you want to learn Orchard Core, this is probably the wrong way to go about it.

Also, repositories were always low-level implementation details in Orchard, that should not be generally used.